# configuring swagger in springboot aplc getting error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger, coding-style

I am trying to configure swagger in my spring application getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.getPatternsCondition()" is null
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings$8.compare(Orderings.java:113) ~[springfox-spi-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings$8.compare(Orderings.java:110) ~[springfox-spi-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using Spring 2.4.17.

I am trying to configure swagger in Spring but i got above error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use spring boot, is it correct?
If yes, have you tried to add

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

in your **application.yaml** file?

also, consider to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>insert_version_here</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of 2 *springfox* dependencies

I had the same issue, but since I have spring boot 2.7 and use actuator I had to migrate to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId> 
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>insert_version_here</version>
</dependency>
```

Some additional refactoring was required but *springfox* actually has a lot of bugs, so it was easier to migrate to *springdoc* than maintain *springfox* implementation.